# xslt single output from a loop

Tags: loops, xslt

I have a source file that looks like this

```
<company>
    <ids>
        <id provider="AAA">123456</id>
    </ids>
    <businessDetails>
        <blocks>
            <block channel="google.com"/>
            <block channel="nokia.com"/>
            <block channel="bing.com"/>
        </blocks>
        <registration>
            <registrationNumber>1352045555</registrationNumber>
            <registrationDate>1983-09-17</registrationDate>
        </registration>
    </businessDetails>
</company>
```

I need to loop through block to see if I should send the registration number. A part of my xslt looks like this

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="s2:businessDetails/s2:blocks">
    <xsl:for-each select="s2:businessDetails/s2:blocks/s2:block">
        <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string(./@channel=&quot;google.com&quot;) , &quot;true&quot;)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string(./@channel=&quot;bing.com&quot;) , &quot;true&quot;)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($var:v1 or $var:v2)='true'">
                                </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <ns0:companyOrgNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../s2:registration/s2:registrationNumber/text()"/>
                </ns0:companyOrgNumber>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:if test="s2:businessDetails/s2:registration/s2:registrationNumber">
        <ns0:companyOrgNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="s2:businessDetails/s2:registration/s2:registrationNumber/text()"/>
        </ns0:companyOrgNumber>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The problem is when I have blocks, but none of them match var:v1 or var:v2 I get several  in the destination file. I only want to have one  if all block are false.

Comment: what is happening with the `userCSharp` stuff? is that particular to your implementation? can it be implemented with standard xslt?

Comment: I get it from the BizTalk mapper, it just compares if the first parameters with the second. It shouldn't be any problem to change it to xslt. I don't think that it will solve my problem with multiple <ns0:companyOrgNumber>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should do this instead:

```
<xsl:if test="s2:businessDetails/s2:blocks[not(s2:block[@channel='google.com']) and not(s2:block[@channel='bing.com'])]">
    <ns0:companyOrgNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="s2:businessDetails/s2:registration/s2:registrationNumber/text()"/>
    </ns0:companyOrgNumber>
</xsl:if>
```

You don't really need to loop through it- Just check for the absence of those nodes.